# GeoJSON JSON file missing Arctic and Antarctic regions

Tags: reactjs, json, geojson

I am building a React app using react-globe.gl for a globe animation. For this globe animation, I need geo coordinates and I tried to use GeoJSON JSON file from https://geojson-maps.ash.ms/, with all of the regions selected, but it seems like there is no Arctic and Antarctic regions included in the JSON file.

Now, I think I have 2 options here:

1. Add Arctic and Antarctic regions manually to the JSON file (which I have no idea how)
2. Find alternative websites that provide JSON file for the needed geo coordinates

What should I do?

Here is part of the GeoJSON JSON file

> {"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","properties":{"featurecla":"Admin-0
> country","scalerank":1,"labelrank":5,"sovereignt":"Costa
> Rica","sov_a3":"CRI","adm0_dif":0,"level":2,"type":"Sovereign
> country","tlc":"1","admin":"Costa
> Rica","adm0_a3":"CRI","geou_dif":0,"geounit":"Costa
> Rica","gu_a3":"CRI","su_dif":0,"subunit":"Costa
> Rica","su_a3":"CRI","brk_diff":0,"name":"Costa
> Rica","name_long":"Costa Rica","brk_a3":"CRI","brk_name":"Costa
> Rica","brk_group":null,"abbrev":"C.R.","postal":"CR","formal_en":"Republic
> of Costa Rica","formal_fr":null,"name_ciawf":"Costa
> Rica","note_adm0":null,"note_brk":null,"name_sort":"Costa
> Rica","name_alt":null,"mapcolor7":3,"mapcolor8":2,"mapcolor9":4,"mapcolor13":2,"pop_est":5047561,"pop_rank":13,"pop_year":2019,"gdp_md":61801,"gdp_year":2019,"economy":"5. Emerging region: G20","income_grp":"3. Upper middle
> income","fips_10":"CS","iso_a2":"CR","iso_a2_eh":"CR","iso_a3":"CRI","iso_a3_eh":"CRI","iso_n3":"188","iso_n3_eh":"188","un_a3":"188","wb_a2":"CR","wb_a3":"CRI","woe_id":23424791,"woe_id_eh":23424791,"woe_note":"Exact
> WOE match as
> country","adm0_iso":"CRI","adm0_diff":null,"adm0_tlc":"CRI","adm0_a3_us":"CRI","adm0_a3_fr":"CRI","adm0_a3_ru":"CRI","adm0_a3_es":"CRI","adm0_a3_cn":"CRI","adm0_a3_tw":"CRI","adm0_a3_in":"CRI","adm0_a3_np":"CRI","adm0_a3_pk":"CRI","adm0_a3_de":"CRI","adm0_a3_gb":"CRI","adm0_a3_br":"CRI","adm0_a3_il":"CRI","adm0_a3_ps":"CRI","adm0_a3_sa":"CRI","adm0_a3_eg":"CRI","adm0_a3_ma":"CRI","adm0_a3_pt":"CRI","adm0_a3_ar":"CRI","adm0_a3_jp":"CRI","adm0_a3_ko":"CRI","adm0_a3_vn":"CRI","adm0_a3_tr":"CRI","adm0_a3_id":"CRI","adm0_a3_pl":"CRI","adm0_a3_gr":"CRI","adm0_a3_it":"CRI","adm0_a3_nl":"CRI","adm0_a3_se":"CRI","adm0_a3_bd":"CRI","adm0_a3_ua":"CRI","adm0_a3_un":-99,"adm0_a3_wb":-99,"continent":"North
> America","region_un":"Americas","subregion":"Central
> America","region_wb":"Latin America &
> Caribbean","name_len":10,"long_len":10,"abbrev_len":4,"tiny":-99,"homepart":1,"min_zoom":0,"min_label":2.5,"max_label":8,"label_x":-84.077922,"label_y":10.0651,"ne_id":1159320525,"wikidataid":"Q800","name_ar":"كوستاريكا","name_bn":"কোস্টা
> রিকা","name_de":"Costa Rica","name_en":"Costa Rica","name_es":"Costa
> Rica","name_fa":"کاستاریکا","name_fr":"Costa Rica","name_el":"Κόστα
> Ρίκα","name_he":"קוסטה ריקה","name_hi":"कोस्टा रीका","name_hu":"Costa
> Rica","name_id":"Kosta Rika","name_it":"Costa
> Rica","name_ja":"コスタリカ","name_ko":"코스타리카","name_nl":"Costa
> Rica","name_pl":"Kostaryka","name_pt":"Costa
> Rica","name_ru":"Коста-Рика","name_sv":"Costa Rica","name_tr":"Kosta
> Rika","name_uk":"Коста-Рика","name_ur":"کوسٹاریکا","name_vi":"Costa
> Rica","name_zh":"哥斯达黎加","name_zht":"哥斯大黎加","fclass_iso":"Admin-0
> country","tlc_diff":null,"fclass_tlc":"Admin-0
> country","fclass_us":null,"fclass_fr":null,"fclass_ru":null,"fclass_es":null,"fclass_cn":null,"fclass_tw":null,"fclass_in":null,"fclass_np":null,"fclass_pk":null,"fclass_de":null,"fclass_gb":null,"fclass_br":null,"fclass_il":null,"fclass_ps":null,"fclass_sa":null,"fclass_eg":null,"fclass_ma":null,"fclass_pt":null,"fclass_ar":null,"fclass_jp":null,"fclass_ko":null,"fclass_vn":null,"fclass_tr":null,"fclass_id":null,"fclass_pl":null,"fclass_gr":null,"fclass_it":null,"fclass_nl":null,"fclass_se":null,"fclass_bd":null,"fclass_ua":null,"filename":"CRI.geojson"},"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-82.54619625520348,9.566134751824677],[-82.93289099804358,9.476812038608173],[-82.92715491405916,9.074330145702916],[-82.71918311230053,8.925708726431495],[-82.86865719270477,8.807266343618522],[-82.82977067740516,8.62629547773237],[-82.91317643912421,8.42351715741907],[-82.96578304719736,8.225027980985985],[-83.50843726269431,8.446926581247283],[-83.71147396516908,8.656836249216866],[-83.59631303580665,8.830443223501419],[-83.63264156770784,9.051385809765321],[-83.90988562695374,9.29080272057358],[-84.30340165885636,9.487354030795714],[-84.64764421256866,9.61553742109571],[-84.71335079622777,9.908051866083852],[-84.97566036654133,10.086723130733006],[-84.91137488477024,9.795991522658923],[-85.11092342806532,9.55703969974131],[-85.33948828809227,9.83454214114866],[-85.66078650586698,9.933347479690724],[-85.79744483106285,10.134885565629034],[-85.79170874707843,10.439337266476613],[-85.65931372754667,10.75433095951172],[-85.94172543002176,10.895278428587801],[-85.7125404528073,11.088444932494824],[-85.5618519762442,11.217119248901597],[-84.90300330273895,10.952303371621896],[-84.67306901725627,11.082657172078143],[-84.35593075228104,10.999225572142905],[-84.19017859570485,10.793450018756674],[-83.89505449088595,10.726839097532446],[-83.65561174186158,10.938764146361422],[-83.40231970898296,10.395438137244653],[-83.01567664257517,9.992982082555557],[-82.54619625520348,9.566134751824677]]]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"featurecla":"Admin-0
> country","scalerank":1,"labelrank":5,"sovereignt":"Nicaragua","sov_a3":"NIC","adm0_dif":0,"level":2,"type":"Sovereign
> country","tlc":"1","admin":"Nicaragua","adm0_a3":"NIC","geou_dif":0,"geounit":"Nicaragua","gu_a3":"NIC","su_dif":0,"subunit":"Nicaragua","su_a3":"NIC","brk_diff":0,"name":"Nicaragua","name_long":"Nicaragua","brk_a3":"NIC","brk_name":"Nicaragua","brk_group":null,"abbrev":"Nic.","postal":"NI","formal_en":"Republic
> of
> Nicaragua","formal_fr":null,"name_ciawf":"Nicaragua","note_adm0":null,"note_brk":null,"name_sort":"Nicaragua","name_alt":null,"mapcolor7":1,"mapcolor8":4,"mapcolor9":1,"mapcolor13":9,"pop_est":6545502,"pop_rank":13,"pop_year":2019,"gdp_md":12520,"gdp_year":2019,"economy":"6. Developing region","income_grp":"4. Lower middle
> income","fips_10":"NU","iso_a2":"NI","iso_a2_eh":"NI","iso_a3":"NIC","iso_a3_eh":"NIC","iso_n3":"558","iso_n3_eh":"558","un_a3":"558","wb_a2":"NI","wb_a3":"NIC","woe_id":23424915,"woe_id_eh":23424915,"woe_note":"Exact
> WOE match as
> country","adm0_iso":"NIC","adm0_diff":null,"adm0_tlc":"NIC","adm0_a3_us":"NIC","adm0_a3_fr":"NIC","adm0_a3_ru":"NIC","adm0_a3_es":"NIC","adm0_a3_cn":"NIC","adm0_a3_tw":"NIC","adm0_a3_in":"NIC","adm0_a3_np":"NIC","adm0_a3_pk":"NIC","adm0_a3_de":"NIC","adm0_a3_gb":"NIC","adm0_a3_br":"NIC","adm0_a3_il":"NIC","adm0_a3_ps":"NIC","adm0_a3_sa":"NIC","adm0_a3_eg":"NIC","adm0_a3_ma":"NIC","adm0_a3_pt":"NIC","adm0_a3_ar":"NIC","adm0_a3_jp":"NIC","adm0_a3_ko":"NIC","adm0_a3_vn":"NIC","adm0_a3_tr":"NIC","adm0_a3_id":"NIC","adm0_a3_pl":"NIC","adm0_a3_gr":"NIC","adm0_a3_it":"NIC","adm0_a3_nl":"NIC","adm0_a3_se":"NIC","adm0_a3_bd":"NIC","adm0_a3_ua":"NIC","adm0_a3_un":-99,"adm0_a3_wb":-99,"continent":"North
> America","region_un":"Americas","subregion":"Central
> America","region_wb":"Latin America &
> Caribbean","name_len":9,"long_len":9,"abbrev_len":4,"tiny":-99,"homepart":1,"min_zoom":0,"min_label":4,"max_label":9,"label_x":-85.069347,"label_y":12.670697,"ne_id":1159321091,"wikidataid":"Q811","name_ar":"نيكاراغوا","name_bn":"নিকারাগুয়া","name_de":"Nicaragua","name_en":"Nicaragua","name_es":"Nicaragua","name_fa":"نیکاراگوئه","name_fr":"Nicaragua","name_el":"Νικαράγουα","name_he":"ניקרגואה","name_hi":"निकारागुआ","name_hu":"Nicaragua","name_id":"Nikaragua","name_it":"Nicaragua","name_ja":"ニカラグア","name_ko":"니카라과","name_nl":"Nicaragua","name_pl":"Nikaragua","name_pt":"Nicarágua","name_ru":"Никарагуа","name_sv":"Nicaragua","name_tr":"Nikaragua","name_uk":"Нікарагуа","name_ur":"نکاراگوا","name_vi":"Nicaragua","name_zh":"尼加拉瓜","name_zht":"尼加拉瓜","fclass_iso":"Admin-0
> country","tlc_diff":null,"fclass_tlc":"Admin-0
> country","fclass_us":null,"fclass_fr":null,"fclass_ru":null,"fclass_es":null,"fclass_cn":null,"fclass_tw":null,"fclass_in":null,"fclass_np":null,"fclass_pk":null,"fclass_de":null,"fclass_gb":null,"fclass_br":null,"fclass_il":null,"fclass_ps":null,"fclass_sa":null,"fclass_eg":null,"fclass_ma":null,"fclass_pt":null,"fclass_ar":null,"fclass_jp":null,"fclass_ko":null,"fclass_vn":null,"fclass_tr":null,"fclass_id":null,"fclass_pl":null,"fclass_gr":null,"fclass_it":null,"fclass_nl":null,"fclass_se":null,"fclass_bd":null,"fclass_ua":null,"filename":"NIC.geojson"},"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":...